# how do i create a button that brings up text and gets rid of text when you click it?

Tags: javascript, html, button, text, dom-events

i can call it in alert but don't know how to get it to display on my website

been looking through videos online but they are not focused on what i'm trying to do

Comment: Brings the text up where? In a pop-up/tool-tip, or in another element, or like an accordion? There's a lot of missing information. [Create a button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), and then add a [listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to it. The function it calls will show/hide the text depending on your use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want something like this?

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("toggle");
let alert = document.getElementById("alert")

 
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
alert.classList.toggle("show")
})
```

```css
.btn {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: #4e4e4e14;
  color: #003cff;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.alert {
  display: none;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: .9rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: #4e4e4e14;
}
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
 <button class="btn " id="toggle">Toogle</button>


 <div class="alert" id="alert">
   <p>
     Sed feugiat et velit ut tincidunt. Ut efficitur sem non rutrum fermentum. Cras cursus erat a lectus elementum, a fringilla felis tempor. Nulla facilisi.
   </p>
 </div>
```